# How to control an on/off switch with raspberry Pi 3(perhaps using Radio)

Tags: raspberry-pi, smart-lights

So I happen to know some python to turn lights on and off in rpi3. Also to automate my home I know how to use relay boards. But the problem is that I have one rpi3 and the light which I want to control is away from it. So radio seemed to be the next option. I am a newbie in this. How to replace a traditional on/off switch with with RF receiver which does certain actions when the rpi3 sends a particular single. I don't know how to setup this particular thing on the rpi3 side and the switch side. Please help me out here. So pls recommend the switch I should use

Comment: you need to decide which switch you want to use before you can start thinking about programming the switch

Comment: @jsotola I don't understand what you just said

Comment: Do you already have the switch, or do you want to buy one?

Comment: I have to buy one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a lot going on with using MQTT in home automation.  Check out the [zigbee2mqtt](https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io) project that allows you to control commercial home automation devices like the ikea [TRÅDFRI Wireless control outlet](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/tradfri-wireless-control-outlet-30356169/) with your own server.